# The output doesn't work and there are information "missing $ inserted"

Tags: mathtools

```
S himpunan. A(S)=\{f:S \to S \mid\text{f pemetaan satu-satu dan pada}\}, T\subsetneq{S}, H =\{f(t) \in{A(S)} \mid f(t) \in{T}; \forall{t \in{T}\}.
```

The output doesn't work and there are information "missing $ inserted"...

I dont know where is incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please edit your post and make your example fully compilable ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) starting with `\documentclass...` and all way down to the `\end{document}`. If you type four spaces in front of a line, that line will by typeset as a source code. Your problem indicates that you are not typesetting mathematics properly, we use dollar for that, e.g. `text before $my math a+b+c$ text after`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this if it fits your needs.

```
% Run: *latex mal-first-math.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Some notes before mathematics. 
S himpunan. $A(S)=\{f:S \to S \mid\text{f pemetaan satu-satu dan pada}\},\ T\subsetneq{S},\ H =\{f(t) \in{A(S)} \mid f(t) \in{T}; \forall\{t \in{T}\}$. Text after mathematics.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I don't think the shebang line will be needed unless the user has the same set up or preference in running LaTeX.

Comment: You are right, that's just message. I should probably start deleting that exclamation mark to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose math in the proper environment: math formulas use special conventions and, while LaTeX knows them, it must be told *when* something is math.

So your input should be:

```
S himpunan. \(A(S)=\{f\colon S \to S \mid \text{\(f\) pemetaan satu-satu dan pada}\}\),
\(T\subsetneq{S}\), \(H =\{f(t) \in A(S) \mid f(t) \in T; \forall t \in T\}\).
```

Note that these are *three* different formulas and each one is surrounded by

```
\( ... \)
```

that mark math. In the condition defining the first set, I used “math inside `\text`”, which is a handier way, because TeX ignores spaces inside math mode, using its own (good) way of spacing symbols.

Note also that `\in` does not take an argument and the same for `\forall`: using less braces will clarify the meaning.

The first long textual description of a set may give paragraphing problems; in this case you can try entering and exiting from math mode

```
\(A(S)=\{f\colon S \to S \mid f\) pemetaan satu-satu dan pada\(\}\),
```

or, probably better, avoiding the set descriptor:

```
we denote by \(A(S)\) the set of injective functions $f\colon S\to S$
```

(is the translation correct?).